# how to make re enter password field in php registration form?

Tags: php, passwords, enter

I made a php registration form connected to the database. I put three fields name, password and email, and I want to know what code should I use to creat a re enter password field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another input field named for example `password2` and then when you POST the form you can check if password1 is equal to password2.

```
<?php 

$password1 = $_POST['password1'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

if ($password1 == $password2) {
    echo "Password is OK";

} else  {
    echo "You entered two different passwords";

}
```

Remember to escape all data coming from POST or GET request

Answer (score 0):

if u have a situation where the length of the password is less, or there is a mismatch then yes you can do that.If you want to do that, then after you check the conditions, set a session variable like

```
`$_SESSION['success']= false //i.e if the condition fails`
```

if you want to retain the previous user inputs then u can use cookies or session variables to do that.
and then redirect back to the registration page. there you can check

```
if(isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success']== false) {
echo '<span> Enter the details again </span>';
you can now take the values of previous inputs and set it like this
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo $_SESSION['username'];?>"/>
...
 }
```

and if you want to empty the fields on page load you can use a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery + a plug-in like this one :
http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/ that allows e-mail validation and what you want to accomplish with password